how do i take the coexpression data in ATTED II and create a gene network in Cytoscape
Using gene coexpression data from ATTED II, how do I format and create a gene network in Cytoscape. Downloading the ATTED II data and uploading to Cytoscape gives me all the nodes (100) but no edges. Am I missing something?
Saving data as cvs (only format available from ATTED II) converting to txt and uploading to Cytoscape doesn't work....

You should probably ask this question over on Bioinformatics StackExchange, but to save you some time, check out the step-by-step instructions here.
